# Automatically set Entity as modified when updating Bridge Table?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables (TableA and TableB) with a bridge table between. I have entities setup properly for both, including navigation properties for the Many-To-Many relationship. Both entities extend an 'AuditBase' class that includes 'Modified/Created Date and ModifiedBy/CreatedBy User'.

Using a commit method, this audit info is automatically updated for any Entities that extend 'AuditBase' and are in the Created/Modified states.

Currently, I have code in certain Save methods to manually set the entity for TableB to 'modified' when items are added/removed from the many-to-many relationship via navigation property. This way the audit data is updated automatically, even though nothing in TableB has actually changed.

I could keep using this pattern, but would like to see if there is some way to remove the manual step of checking for updates to bridge table. Is there any way that I could detect pending changes to this Bridge table prior to calling Save (in my commit method), and flag the associated Entity as modified?

Configuration of the Bridge Table in question -

```
            this.HasMany(u => u.TableA)
                .WithMany(r => r.TableB)
                .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.ToTable("TableA_TableB", "dbo");
                         m.MapLeftKey("TableA_Id");
                         m.MapRightKey("TableB_Id");
                     });
```

And here is the code used to find the modified entities right now -

```
    this._context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var addedAuditedEntities = 
        this._context.ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditModelBase>().Where(p => p.State == 
        EntityState.Added).Select(p => p.Entity);
    var modifiedAuditedEntities = 
        this._context.ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditModelBase>().Where(p => p.State == 
        EntityState.Modified).Select(p => p.Entity);
```

Comment: Could you add a code sample and the expected data output? That would help us better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Added some example code.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide any sample code but you can override `SaveChanges` method and control the related entities states.

something like this. eg.

```cs
 public class AppDbContext : DbContex
....

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

            var modifiled = ChangeTracker.Entries<BRIDGE_TABLE_ENTITY>().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Deleted || x.State == EntityState.Modified);
            foreach (var item in modifiled)
            {
                 item.Property("TABLEA_REF_PROP_NAME").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                 item.Property("TABLEB_REF_PROP_NAME").EntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled =
               false; // for performance reasons, to avoid calling DetectChanges() again.
            var result = base.SaveChanges();
            ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            return result;
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**

depending on your sample code the short answer is *if you need to use `ChangeTracker` for your bridge table, you must create a separate entity to provide access to it*

Comment: This is the direction I want to go, and it is how it currently tracks changes for entities that extend AuditBase. However, the issue running into is the Bridge table does not have an actual entity class, it is only configured like so -

`            this.HasMany(u => u.TableA)
                .WithMany(r => r.TableB)
                .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.ToTable("TableA_TableB", "dbo");
                         m.MapLeftKey("TableA_Id");
                         m.MapRightKey("TableB_Id");
                     });
`

Comment: if you want to control your bridge table states. you have to create an actual entity for it.

Comment: For controlling, do you mean also detecting states? I would like the control the state of the normal tables by detecting the state of the bridge tables.

Comment: yes. ef must track your bridge table too ...using the standard way of many to many relationships is your only option now. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration
the short answer is if you need to use ChangeTracker you must create a separated entity

Comment: @David but maybe you can use `IsModified` to check the collections are modified or not. did you tried that? `if (itemA.Property("TableB").IsModified )`. I'm not sure it works or not